# Uncertain what codes in print mean

Tags: python, ansi-escape

I was looking for a method for moving the terminal cursor in Python. The following method worked perfectly, but I don't know why or how it worked. After investigating, I concluded that this isn't a regular expression. If someone is able to explain this to me or give me a keyword I can search for, I would appreciate it very much.

```py
def move(y, x):
    print("\033[%d;%dH" % (y, x))
```

Comment: Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Note that `\033` is the escape character. See also [this blogpost](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html) which gives a nice overview with Python.

Comment: %d means injecting a digit (int) in string, which is specified in string declaration that it needs 2 integes as parameter, it will be injected if you put % sign and parameters https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html